# Тормозной полёт панорамирования при 10к меток в кластере

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть тысячи меток в кластере. Чтобы показать юзеру запрошенную метку, скрипт делает туда мап и зум

```
map.panTo([coord[0],coord[1]+0.0035]).then(function () {
  map.setZoom(17);
  //дальше балун
});
```

Если метки рядом - все плавно и хорошо. Если же метки далеко, карта сначала сама делает анзум, потом панорамирование, потом мой зум. Кластеры пересчитываются 2.5 раза, карта тормозит с белыми квадратами, все коряво.

Вопрос: как временно отключить работу кластеризатора целиком, либо как отключить автозум полета при панорамировании?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо map.panTo() можно использовать map.setCenter() или методу panTo можно передавать опции чтобы запретить отзумливание https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Map-docpage/#method_detail__panTo .